# where to ask a question about a wrong suffix?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I wrote a text Under Libre Office and erroneously named the file with a .txt suffix. And closed it. When I tried to open it. it was said corrupt. And was displayed in non understandable characters. What to do? I tried to rename it with .odt suffix. I changed nothing.

Comment: Open Libre Office and drag-n-drop the file onto it. If it opens properly save it with a better name.

Answer (score 4):

Super User would be the appropriate place to ask such a question.